# Fancybox just links to image like normal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I'm working on Fancybox, in combination with PHP, and when I click a link, it's supposed to do its whole "lightbox" thing, but it doesn't. It just links to the image, which opens in the same tab. This is what I'm doing in HTML:

```
<td><a class="fancybox" href="public/products/' . $result['img'] . '">test</a></td>
```

(This code already is in an `echo` block)

The jQuery isn't really interesting, since that's just

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

So how is it, that this fairly simple jQuery plugin doesn't work as expected?

Comment: `$(".fancybox").fancybox();` you are using it inside the ready function ?

Comment: Any error in console on page loading ? Because you are doing perfect I don't see any sign of error yet!

Comment: Is this for a wordpress site or custom? If wordpress are there any conflicting plugins and/or could it be the ordering of other possible scripts being loaded?

Comment: and other jquery functions are working?

Comment: need more details, specifically if anything is outputted to the console